# How to achieve dynamic UIView masking?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to achieve a sort of dynamic UIView masking effect. Here is a sketch:
[image]

So as you can see, I'm trying to create a UIView that can effectively cut through an image to reveal the image behind it. I already know how to return an image with a mask statically, however I would like the "revealer" to be draggable (I'll use pan gesture) and live.

Does anyone have any ideas or starting points on how to achieve this? Thanks

(NOTE: My demo says White layer, but I'd actually like to show another image or photo).

Comment: What code are you starting with?

Comment: None, I'm looking for ideas or tips on how to get the UIView to cut through an image.

Comment: I'm sorry, not really sure what effect you want on the non-transparent part, but can't you have a view that is much larger than your picture, has a 100% transparent square in the middle and its borders are white with say 60% opacity? Then drag this view around? No need for masking or anything - just a UIScrollView.

Comment: @PeterSarnowski Sorry for the confusion. Basically I have two images stacked on top of the other. I want a small rectangular area to cut through the top image so I can show the bottom image.

Comment: I am having same issue in my current project. Appreciate if you can share the code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

masking an image is not that difficult.

This link shows the basics. 
http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html

But personally I think i would make 2 UIImage views and crop the content of the draggable UIView.  I'm not sure but I would expect that clipping and panning the second image will be less computationally expensive then applying the mask and will get you a better frame rate.

So I would do:  UIImageView of the full image.  A UIView on top of it with a white and some transparency setting to make it look white, then a UIImageView with the image either places or cropped so that only the correct section is showing.

Comment: Forgive my description, the "white" layer is actually going to be another image. So its 2 images stacked on one another, and I need a rectangle to cut through the middle image to show the bottom image. Any ideas appreciate.d Thanks!

Comment: yeah. same thing for the most part. use 3 UIImageViews. crop the top one to make it appear like it cuts through the middle one. it's not really masked but it will appear the same to the end user.

Comment: Hey, sounds interesting. What do you mean by "crop the top one"? I'm thinking my top UIImageView would have to somehow replicate the bottom  image at that exact location (since the rectangle is draggable). Thanks

Comment: Hi, thank you, I found out what you meant by cropping an image. I've got my prototype working out. Thanks!

Comment: @user339946 can you share any resources regarding this topic? Provided above link is not working for me.