# How to clip image to UIView animating over it?

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation, clipping

I've been looking around here and seeing lots of questions that seem related, but I haven't found anything that's exactly what I need.

I have three UIViews that are animating inside a custom viewController. I want there to be a static background inside the viewController that is only revealed within the clipping bounds of the UIViews.

It's kind of like spotlights on a prison yard: the background should stay in one place, but as the spotlights move you can see different parts of it. Except that I don't need circles, regular old UIView frames are fine.

For instance, it seems like what I need is in the answer to this question: [How to achieve dynamic UIView masking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866810/how-to-achieve-dynamic-uiview-masking)

...the answerer provides a link to a page that shows how to statically mask an image, and then the answerer says "But personally I think i would make 2 UIImage views and crop the content of the draggable UIView"--without any info on how to do that.

How do you do that?

Comment: I couldn't find the link you are looking for, so I'm not sure if this is different from what it is suggesting in terms of static CALayers, but I think I would make a CALayer mask which is fully opaque except for a square the size of your UIView, then animate its transform using CoreAnimation. Would something like that be acceptable here?

Comment: That seems possible, but way more complex than what is being suggested in the other post.